# Github online create pull request to another branch from existing pull request

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I have two main branches A and B. I have a fix in branch C which is based on A. I have raised a PR from C -> A (say P1). Currently to put the same fixes in B, new branch has to be created from B (say D), fixes cherry picked from C, and then PR raised from D -> B . Is there a way to raise this PR online from P1, such that I do not have to manually cherry pick?
This option exists in Axure Devops

Answer (score 1):

Not really, considering the [Azure DevOps PR cherry-pick option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#cherry-pick-a-pull-request) does precisely what you are describing:

> In a completed pull request, select `Cherry-pick`, or for an active pull request, select `Cherry-pick from the ...` menu.
> Cherry-picking a pull request in this way creates a new branch with the copied changes.
> Merge into a target branch in a second pull request.

That option does not yet exist on GitHub.